Showing $\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{(x+y)(x+z)}\geq\;x+y+z+\sqrt{3xy+3yz+3zx}$, for positive $x$, $y$, $z$

Let $x$, $y$, $z$ be positive numbers, prove that
$$\sqrt{(x + y)(x + z)} + \sqrt{(x + y)(y + z)} + \sqrt{(z + y)(x + z)} \\ \geq \; x + y + z + \sqrt{3xy + 3yz + 3zx}$$

I tried use following for the first term on the left hand side, and then do the cyclic summation.

$\sqrt{(x + y)(x + z)}\geq x+\sqrt{yz}$ by Cauchy–Schwarz inequality;
$\sqrt{\frac{x^2+xy+yz+xz}{4}}\geq \frac{1}{4}(\sqrt{x^2}+\sqrt{xy}+\sqrt{yz}+\sqrt{xz})$ by Jesen's  inequality;

But all these methods failed.
Another form of the inequality is $\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{x^2+Q}\geq \sum_{cyc}\sqrt{x^2} +
\sqrt{3Q}$ with $Q=xy+yz+zx$ so I doubt just transform a single term and  do the cyclic summation is not a good idea for proving this.

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

The inequality can be written as:
$$ \Leftrightarrow2\left(x + y + z - \sqrt {3(xy + xz + yz)}\right) - \sum_{cyc}\left(\sqrt {x+y} - \sqrt {x+z}\right)^{2}\geq0$$
$$\Leftrightarrow  \sum_{cyc}\frac {(x - y)^2\left(z + \dfrac {4z^{2} + xy + xz + yz}{2\sqrt {(z + x)(z + y)} + \sqrt {3(xy + xz + yz)}}\right)}{\left(x + y + z + \sqrt {3(xy + xz + yz)}\right)\left(\sqrt {z + x} + \sqrt {z + y}\right)^2}\geq0$$

Could you explain more on the second equivalence? I cannot follow your idea.

You will use $\sqrt{a} - \sqrt{b} = \dfrac{a-b}{\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}}$

I used this and still cannot figure out why the equivalence holds...

It holds when $x=y=z$

I mean, I don't konw how to transform to the last expression, it's too complicated... Could you write more details on the transformations?

$x+y+z - \sqrt{3(xy+yz+zx)} = \dfrac{(x+y+z)^2 - 3(xy+yz+zx)}{x+y+z+\sqrt{3(xy+yz+zx)} = \dfrac{\dfrac{1}{2}((x-y)^2+(y-z)^2+(z-x)^2)}{{x+y+z+\sqrt{3(xy+yz+zx)}$ and do the similiar things
